# Python extract text in dataframe into multiple columns

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe which I'd like to convert into multiple columns. An example of dataframe showed below:

```
Name      | originalMessage
----------|------------------
Peter     | [{'message': 'DLJ', 'time': '2020-05-30 21:53:11', 'role': 'User'}]
Jason     | [{'message': 'Ex Student', 'time': '2020-05-30 21:53:11', 'role': 'User'}]
Steven    | [{'message': 'Class 42', 'time': '2020-06-02 09:35:45', 'role': 'User'}, {'message': {'type': 'text', 'text': 'This is another description'}, 'time': '2020-06-02 09:35:47', 'role': 'Admin'}]
```

I would like to convert to

```
Name      | message                         | time                   | role
Peter     | DLJ                             | 2020-05-30 21:53:11    | User
Jason     | DLJ                             | 2020-05-30 21:53:11    | User
Steven    | Class 42                        | 2020-06-02 09:35:45    | User
Steven    | This is another description     | 2020-06-02 09:35:47    | User
```

Thank you

Comment: So what have you tried ?

Comment: Are the contents of the column `originalMessage` python objects or strings? what does `type(df.iloc[0]['originalMessage'])` give you?

Comment: @Loïc I've tried .str.extract() to separate into multiple columns but I got ```NaN```

Comment: @user32882 It's a list.

Comment: Then the answer provided by @Abhishek kumar should work for you...

Comment: I just checked your input dataframe again. You can't generalize this properly because the 'message' key in your inner dict for "Steven" has unpredictable contents. Sometimes it contains a string, other times it contains another dict... You have to have some structure to your data before you can do this sort of thing...

Comment: @user32882 You're correct. I've tried Abhishek script and it didn't work. The column contains unpredictable number of dicts. I'm trying to find a way to count the number of dict and will try to extract them.

Comment: @ThanawatRaibroycharoen in that case I would argue that you need to solve this problem earlier in your script. How are you reading this data? How does it end up as a nested `dict`? That's the underlying problem here...

Comment: @user32882 I've solved it. I extract the source data from mongodb. But the data is unstructured. I need to transform it to dataframe for further analysis. Thanks for your help.

I use dataframe.explode to extract the list and do while loop to extract every rows.

Answer (score 1):

This should be helpful and simple .

```
data = {"Name":["Peter" , "Jason"] , 
        "originalMessage":[[{'message': 'DLJ', 'time': '2020-05-30 21:53:11', 'role': 'User'}] , 
                          [{'message': 'Ex Student', 'time': '2020-05-30 21:53:11', 'role': 'User'}]]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df2 = {"message":[], "time":[], "role":[]}
for t in df.originalMessage.values:
    for c in t[0].keys():
        df2[c] = t[0][c]
        
df2["Name"] = df.Name
dd = pd.DataFrame(df2)
```